# Unit of area in RTL Compiler

Tags: asic, cadence

After compiling my design using RTL compiler targeting 45nm library, the tool gives me an area report as below:

```
   Type    Instances    Area    Area %
---------------------------------------
sequential      2237  19102.387   15.8
inverter        6982   9830.896    8.1
buffer           535   1255.847    1.0
logic          33180  91031.529   75.1
---------------------------------------
total          42934 121220.659  100.0
```

What is the unit of the Area column and what is the meaning of this area number?

Comment: Best way to find out will be either the tool's own documentation or your tool vendor's support chain (tech support or their own forums).

Comment: Thank you Brian. I cannot find the RTL compiler mannual. The tech support is normally too slow for me. Their forum is not very active. Ha, I am complaining too much. I will try to find the documentation on our server.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, here is what the mannual says, ""The area report gives a summary of the area of each component in the current design. The report gives the number of gates and the area size based on the specified technology library. Levels of hierarchy are indented in the report." I dont find this explanation clear.

Comment: Ah the clue is "the area size based on the specified technology library" ... if you refer tho the docs for that library, they ought to specify the area units (mm^2, um^2 or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers from Cadence forum:

If your library says the are of a buffer is 10 square units and your design has 2 buffers, RC should report an area of 20. A few things to keep in mind:

- most libraries use square microns for units but some use their own reference unit which may or may not be documented in library
- RC report cell area as well as area. area includes cell area and an estimate of net area. As mentioned before, the cell area is not estimated whereas net is.

http://www.cadence.com/Community/forums/p/25863/1322431.aspx#1322431

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the log/verbose log file as it specifies which units it is setting for its calculations. You can find it in the design loading stage
2. Check the LEF for area units

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the library you are using. You can check library data sheet for more information. Like TSMC xxx library, 2-Input NAND(ND2D0BWP) gate count is 1; 2-Input AND (AN2D0BWP) gate count is 1.5.